# Hashtable. Name history. Why not HashTable?

Tags: java, terminology, history, hashtable

we know:

```
ArrayList;
LinkedList;
TreeMap
```

and other... and all names in CamelCase format, but why `Hashtable`, not `HashTable`?

it is unprincipled question, just wondering :)

Comment: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5415067

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Hashtable` was created in Java v1. The consistent naming conventions for collections were established later, in Java2, when the other classes were published as part of the brand new Java Collection Framework.

Which btw made `Hashtable` obsolete, so it should not be used in new code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the java naming conventions were well established by Java 1.1.  There are actually very few "violations".

Comment: @Stephen C, you are most probably right in general, my question referred specifically to the naming of collection classes. I edited my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

It's a typo. Same as `Cloneable` (should be Clonable). Or `Referer` (should be Referrer)

Comment: Bad answer | Cloneable is correct: http://phras.in/cloneable/clonable | Referer is correct: http://phras.in/referer/referrer | :P |