# Why is this violation of naming convention in java?

Tags: java

Is there any special reason for having the class names `java.util.Hashtable` with a small "t" instead of `java.util.HashTable`?? and also the `class java.awt.Checkbox` also has small "b". Why is this violation of naming convention?? Almost spent two hours trying to figure out why the compiler didn't fine `java.util.HashTable`. Are there any other classes that violate the naming convention??

Comment: `Hashtable` is deprecated, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966983/hashtable-name-history-why-not-hashtable - `Checkbox` is valid because "checkbox" is a single word, at least in American English dictionaries.

Comment: are there any other classes that follow this type of naming??

Comment: hashtable isn't technically deprecated (there is no @deprecated)

Comment: hashtable is deprecated?? the oracle tutorial on JSlider's told me to use hashtable. What is the alternative? hash map?

Comment: Use an IDE! Any decent IDE will tell you immediately what you typed wrong and provide suggestions. java.util.Hash Ctrl+Space, bam! would you like java.util.Hashtable or java.util.HashMap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is not agreed whether "hashtable" and "checkbox" aren't single words - they might be viewed as such. See [wikipedia about checkbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkbox).

But "hashtable" is quite rarer than "Hash table", we can simply say "they got it wrong". Luckily, they fixed it with `HashMap`, and now you should almost never use `Hashtable`

Comment: But wouldn't that count for "hashmap" as well? Or is "hashtable" considered a single word due to its prevalence in data structures literature? I always thought it was simply because `Hashtable` has beeen around since JDK 1.0 and they simply weren't as thorough regarding names yet.

Comment: well, that one too, but they wouldn't name it that way originally, if it was 100% whether it's one or two words

Comment: Interesting... I've wondered about that before. Any resources that show discussion between spec developers regarding this?